# Send throttling by domain

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder

Is there a way to throttle email sends by domain name (within Journey Builder)?

In the midst of restarting our IP warming and want limit how many emails go to specific subscribers based on their domain.

Comment: Perhaps have a split based on domain and then have a UI send with the appropriate throttling on each domains path?

Comment: I think that would be a good option.  Thanks @Gortonington